# mysql insert multple rows with different values

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert mulitple rows in mysql using a single insert statement?

I have a table like this:

```
id | firstname | lastname
```

and a big list of names to insert.

I would like to do this using a single insert.

Comment: Yes, [review the `INSERT` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). The pattern is `VALUES (...),(...),(...)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an INSERT-SELECT query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,firstname,lastname) SELECT 1,'aa','bb' UNION SELECT 3,'bb','cc'
```

Comment: No need for a `UNION` hack. There's a real supported syntax for this.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You are right but I wanted to show that a SELECT clause could be used as a source of values to insert.

Comment: I prefer the `union all` syntax.  It is standard and works in all databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have your **big list** of names in a file (e.g. in a comma separated format)

```
firstname,lastname
Jhon,Doe
Jane,Doe
```

and your table schema looks something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastname varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) to import this list into your table

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/names.csv' INTO TABLE table1
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or \r\n 
  IGNORE 1 LINES -- ignore the header line in the file
(firstname, lastname);
```